# Psycopg copy_expert method - How to use properly

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg

I'm trying to run code like this:

```
query = "copy  (select email from my_table) TO 'STDOUT' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '|', QUOTE '^', HEADER FALSE)"
out_file = StringIO()
cursor.copy_expert(query, out_file, size=8192)
```

Using the [copy_expert cursor method](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert).

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etl/scripts/scratch.py", line 32, in <module>
    cursor.copy_expert(query, out_file, size=8192)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

I'm not in a position to run it as a superuser and it seems like that shouldn't be required since I'm not touching any real files.

Comment: StringIO is something like a memory file if I remember correctly. This seems not be supported by psycopg2. Why do you need this StringIO?

Comment: I want to do everything in memory.  All the docs says is required is "file-like object to write data into. It must have a write() method."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are [two variants of `COPY TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

- `COPY TO STDOUT`, which streams data back to the client, and
- `COPY TO 'filename'`, which writes to a server-side file (requiring superuser privileges).

Your `COPY` statement has quotes around the `STDOUT` keyword, causing it to be interpreted as a filename. Just remove them.

Comment: Yes, I verified that worked to remove the quotes.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can also use a csv module instead of `copy_expert`.

```
import csv

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

_url = f"snowflake://user:test124/snow.com:443/DB/WAREHOUSE/ACCOUNT"
with open("sample.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    with Session(create_engine(_url).engine) as session:
        result = session.execute("select * from my_table")
        data = result.fetchall()
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(data)
```